# Add restriction to element in extension in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I have this complex type:

```
<xs:complexType name="Date">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Day" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:element name="Month" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:element name="Year" type="xs:integer"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I want to create a type that extends the above while putting restriction to *Year* element like:

```
<xs:complexType name="DateOfBirth">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="Date">
      <!--
        restriction: 1990 <= year <= 2005
      -->
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

There are more types I want to create that also extend *Date*, and each of them has different restrictions.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: XSD 1.1 with assertions? Or XSD 1.0?

Comment: I'm using XSD 1.0

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be a two-step process: first define a type that restricts `DateOfBirth`, then define a type that extends this restricted type. Or you can do it the other way around if you prefer. It's simplest (and most reusable) in my view if you define all these types as named global complex type declarations rather than using anonymous inline types.